# How can I find mean values in a column based on a different column?

Tags: r

I have this dataframe, and I am trying to find the mean of the index values for same ID and assign NA's for the rest (Or just keep the value like in the intended output).

```
ID    hot   index
41400 10      2
41400 12      2
41400 75      4
41401 89      5 
41401 25      3 
41401 100     6 
20445 67      4
20445 89      6
20445 4       1
20443 67      5
20443 120.2   7
20443 140.5   8
20423 170.5   10
20423 78.1    5
```

The intended output is

```
ID    hot     index mean
41400 10      2      2.67
41400 12      2      2.67
41400 75      4      2.67
41401 89      5      4.67 
41401 25      3      4.67
41401 100     6      4.67
20445 67      4      3.67
20445 89      6      3.67
20445 4       1      3.67
20443 67      5      6.67
20443 120.2   7      6.67
20443 140.5   8      6.67
20423 170.5   10     12.5
20423 78.1    5      12.5
```

I am not sure how to go about it. Could you please help?

Thanks

Comment: The output doesn't match up. There is no ID 20423 in the input. Incorrect output is not helpful for testing.

Comment: Mean, sorry. I was in the middle of editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data.frame is named `dd`, you can use the `ave` function which performs functions at a group level. For example

```
meaned<-with(dd, ave(index, ID, FUN=mean))
cbind(dd, meaned)
```

Comment: I am guessing, replacing sum=mean will get me mean? Thank you.

Comment: @maximusyoda - `ave` gives a mean by default, so `ave(index,ID)` will do it.

Comment: Awesome. This is a nifty function I had never heard of.

Comment: @maximusyoda. Try to edit before you hit submit. You really changed the question there.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(dd)[,meaned:=mean(index), by=ID]
```

You mentioned in the post `assign NA's for the rest`, if it is to assign NA's to all the rows except the first for each IDs

```
 setDT(dd)[,c("meaned", "N") :=  {list(mean(index) , 1:.N)}, by=ID][N!=1, meaned:=NA][,N:=NULL]

    dd
 #       ID   hot index   meaned
 #1: 41400  10.0     2 2.666667
 #2: 41400  12.0     2       NA
 #3: 41400  75.0     4       NA
 #4: 41401  89.0     5 4.666667
 #5: 41401  25.0     3       NA
 #6: 41401 100.0     6       NA
 #7: 20445  67.0     4 3.666667
 #8: 20445  89.0     6       NA
 #9: 20445   4.0     1       NA
#10: 20443  67.0     5 6.666667
#11: 20443 120.2     7       NA
#12: 20443 140.5     8       NA
#13: 20423 170.5    10 7.500000
#14: 20423  78.1     5       NA
```