# How can I find frequency of month per ID?

Tags: r

I have this dataframe (all), and I am trying to find the highest frequency of season in every ID.

```
ID    hot   index season
41400 10      2   DJF  
41400 12      2   DJF
41400 75      4   JJA
41401 89      5   SON 
41401 25      3   SON
41401 100     6   SON
20445 67      4   MAM 
20445 89      6   MAM
20445 4       1   DJF
20443 67      5   SON
20443 120.2   7   SON
20443 140.5   8   SON 
20423 170.5   10  DJF
20423 78.1    5   MAM
```

The intended output is

---

```
    ID    hot   index season
    41400 10      2   DJF  
    41400 12      2   DJF
    41400 75      4   DJF
    41401 89      5   SON 
    41401 25      3   SON
    41401 100     6   SON
    20445 67      4   MAM 
    20445 89      6   MAM
    20445 4       1   MAM
    20443 67      5   SON
    20443 120.2   7   SON
    20443 140.5   8   SON 
    20423 170.5   10  DJF
    20423 78.1    5   DJF
```

As you can see from this question, I have previously calculated mean for same data using

[How can I find mean values in a column based on a different column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027618/how-can-i-find-mean-values-in-a-column-based-on-a-different-column)

```
meaned<-with(all, ave(index, ID, FUN=mean))
cbind(all, meaned)
```

I am doing this, but I think I am on the wrong path

```
seasonfreq1<-count(all,c(ID,"season"))
seasonfreq2<-with(ID, ave(freq, ID, FUN=max))
```

But I am not sure how to find frequency (or if there is another method for it). Maybe lapply?Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with `data.table` (assuming your data called `df`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, freq := .N, by = list(ID, season)]
df[, season := season[which.max(freq)], by = ID][, freq := NULL] # You can leave the `freq` column if you want to see the frequencies

#       ID   hot index season
# 1: 41400  10.0     2    DJF
# 2: 41400  12.0     2    DJF
# 3: 41400  75.0     4    DJF
# 4: 41401  89.0     5    SON
# 5: 41401  25.0     3    SON
# 6: 41401 100.0     6    SON
# 7: 20445  67.0     4    MAM
# 8: 20445  89.0     6    MAM
# 9: 20445   4.0     1    MAM
#10: 20443  67.0     5    SON
#11: 20443 120.2     7    SON
#12: 20443 140.5     8    SON
#13: 20423 170.5    10    DJF
#14: 20423  78.1     5    DJF
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ave`, maybe something like:

```
with(all,ave(season,ID,FUN=function(x) names(sort(table(x),decreasing=TRUE)[1])))
# [1] DJF DJF DJF SON SON SON MAM MAM MAM SON SON SON DJF DJF
#Levels: DJF JJA MAM SON
```